# Creating geom object from list of lat, long coordinates

Tags: geometry, python-2.7, well-known-text

I have this geometry key that looks like this from which I want to create a Geom object so something like this `MultiPolygon(((-xx.73833882299999 yy.41161324700006, -xx.73826573899998 yy.41172750400005....)))`

```
"geometry" : {
      "type" : "MultiPolygon",
      "coordinates" : [ [ [ [ -xx.73833882299999, yy.41161324700006 ], [ -xx.73826573899998, yy.41172750400005 ], [ -xx.73841407199996, yy.411798780000034 ], [ -xx.73847373299998, yy.411705506000033 ], [ -xx.73838981999995, yy.41166518500007 ], [ -xx.73840324199995, yy.411644202000044 ], [ -xx.73833882299999, yy.41161324700006 ], [ -xx.73833882299999, yy.41161324700006 ] ] ] ]
    }
```

Is there a function in Python that helps to do that?

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a geoJSON file. Assuming you want to convert this into a shapefile using python, perhaps this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44049679/geojson-to-shapefile-using-python.

If you have access to ESRI software, there is a tool called [json to features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/json-to-features.htm) which may be of use to you as well.